# Several compiler errors in Razor code, that disappear when changing order of unrelated lines

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

Im using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit), Version 17.2.4 and .net core 6.

In the `.cshtml` file I'm trying to check if `ViewData["x"]` is null or not like this:

```
@using System.Collections
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = @Localizer["Title"];
    var list = ViewData["EmailTypes"] != null ? (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["EmailTypes"] : null;
}
```

Im getting this errors:

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error (active)  CS0119  'IEnumerable' is a type, which is not valid in the given context    X

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error (active)  CS1026  ) expected

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error (active)  CS1003  Syntax error, ':' expected

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error (active)  RZ1025  The "SelectListItem" element was not closed.  All elements must be either self-closing or have a matching end tag.

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error (active)  RZ1006  The code block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.

[image]

---

But if I do like this:

```
@using System.Collections
    @{
        var list = ViewData["EmailTypes"] != null ? (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["EmailTypes"] : null;
        ViewData["Title"] = @Localizer["Title"];
    }
```

all errors disappear
[image]

how come this happens, and whats the best way to check if IEnumerableViewData["x"] is null or not?

Comment: Try something like: ```IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list = ViewData["EmailTypes"] ?? null;```

Comment: @JHBonarius I removed the `@` int `@Localizer` and this fixed my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `IEnumerable<T>` is in `System.Collections.Generic`, not in `System.Collections`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewData["Title"] = @Localizer["Title"];`

There's a "lost"(?) `@` symbol in that line, which confused the Razor compiler. Check [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor) for a proper syntax rules.

Comment: Does this explain why the errors are gone when he merely swapped the order of the two lines? Not familiar with compiler, so it seems strange to me

Comment: You are completely right, I applied the changes but it's all the same

Comment: It works only when I put `var list = ViewData["EmailTypes"] != null ? (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["EmailTypes"] : null;` before `ViewData["Title"] = @Localizer["Title"];`